# Function won't print anything

Tags: python-3.x, function

I am trying to get the output of this function but I can't get anything, I tried to change elements but couldn't get anything.

```
def player_input():

marker = " "
while marker != "x" and marker != "o":
        marker = input("Player 1, choose x or o: ")

        player1 = marker

        if player1 == "x":
            player2 = "o"

        else:
            player2 = "x"

print(player_input)
```

Comment: Do you mean to _call_ `player_input`? E.g. `player_input()`?

Answer (score 1):

You mussed do two things:

1. add opening and closing brackets when you are calling the function so change `print(player_input)` to `print(player_input())`. This runs the function rather than simply printing a pointer to the function.
2. to get the value of a variable from a function you must return that value. So add the line `return player2`, for instance, if you want to get the value of the variable player2 when calling the function.

Comment: nevermind josh,thank you very much it worked eventually,what you said about the brackets helped me a lot but my mistake was that i placed the print function wrong in the code